# MVC RadioButtonFor outputs same ID for every element

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, radio-button

I have an EditorTemplate that has a group of Radio Buttons in it.

```
<div class="vote">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Vote, 1, new { @class = "rdbn" })
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Vote, 2, new { @class = "rdbn" })
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Vote, 3, new { @class = "rdbn" })
</div>
```

When I run the application the output is:

```
<div class="vote">
    <input id="Reviews_0__Vote" type="radio" class="myCssClass" value="1" name="Reviews[0].Vote">
    <input id="Reviews_0__Vote" type="radio" class="myCssClass" value="2" name="Reviews[0].Vote">
    <input id="Reviews_0__Vote" type="radio" class="myCssClass" value="3" name="Reviews[0].Vote">
</div> 
<div class="vote">
    <input id="Reviews_1__Vote" type="radio" class="myCssClass" value="1" name="Reviews[1].Vote">
    <input id="Reviews_1__Vote" type="radio" class="myCssClass" value="2" name="Reviews[1].Vote">
    <input id="Reviews_1__Vote" type="radio" class="myCssClass" value="3" name="Reviews[1].Vote">
</div>
```

The problem is that the ID of the `input` element is the same every time. I am trying to run some jquery on these radio buttons but obviously I cant if the ID is the same for every single element. Is there an easy way to make the ID unique each time without specifying it manually using an HTML Attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save you having to set the id attribute each time, you could create an extension method similar to the following (untested):

```
public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonListFor<TModel, TProperty>
    (this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, 
        IEnumerable<object> values, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        //Create a unique id based on the radio button value
        if (!htmlAttributes.ContainsKey("id"))
            htmlAttributes.Add("id", string.Format("{0}_{1}", htmlHelper.IdFor(expression), value.ToString()));

        builder.Append(htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, value, htmlAttributes));
    }

    return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString());
}
```

Then you could use this extension in your view:

```
<div class="vote">
    @Html.RadioButtonListFor(x => x.Vote, new[] {1, 2, 3},  new { @class = "rdbn" })
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going by ID, you could just use jQuery to find the individual radio buttons by value:

```
$("#idOfRadioButton").find(":radio[value=1]")
```

Comment: +1 to counter the downvote. No need to over-complicate things when the solution is as simple as this (or manually write the html and set the ID yourself rather than using the helper).

Comment: This completely defeats the point. Having the same id on the form is invalid HTML.